# Sharepoint AV detection in path suggested to whitelist

Tags: sharepoint-server, anti-virus

I am facing a detection in path that is listed by Microsoft to be added as Exclusion at - https://support.office.com/en-us/article/certain-folders-may-have-to-be-excluded-from-antivirus-scanning-when-you-use-file-level-antivirus-software-in-sharepoint-01cbc532-a24e-4bba-8d67-0b1ed733a3d9

C:\Users\xx-xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\gthrsvc_OSearch14\xxxx_yyy.pptx\ppt/slides/_rels/slide39.xml.rels

The file path in exclusioon list also says  to exclude -Drive:\Users\ServiceAccount\AppData\Local\Temp

I am confused if there really maybe any threat in the file listed above(pptx) and what about other threats in the temp folder if I whitelist it ?

Answer (score 0):

Antivirus can detect normal SharePoint files and can delete, modify or interfere the performance of overall SharePoint performance.

Location C:\Users\xx-xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\gthrsvc_OSearch14... mention by you, is basically for search service application to store the data temporarily while performing crawl.

If these folders are not excluded from antivirus, it can slow down the performance of SharePoint.

There should not be any threats in excluding these folders from antivirus scanning as long as you have firewall placed for external traffic.

Comment: But I am still not sure why is PowerPoint files getting detected by McAfee, performance issue can be checked but what if PowerPoint file listed is really malicious ? Would it be good to white list the path ?

Comment: Its a data as part of gatherer so it should be temporarily stored and automatically deleted once crawl completes. Original data will be stored in search index. You can check once if this PPT exist in SharePoint or not.. There is a option to scan during upload and download which should prevent all malicious files to be present in SharePoint. Central admin->Security->General Security->Manage antivirus settings... For gatherer location, you need to exclude them from scan otherwise it will slow the search crawl performance.